# woocommerce how to get cat id in content-product.php

Tags: plugins

I installed the woocommerce plugin.

my page url is like this http://sitename.com/product-category/products-and-service/servicecat1/

products-and-service - is the main category
servicecat1 - is the sub category

In this page the list of products are displayed.

I want to get the category id of the subcategory (i.e servicecat1)

I used the following code

```
  $q_cat = get_query_var('cat');
```

AND

```
     $term_list = wp_get_post_terms('servicecat1','product_cat');
```

But it is not working.

How to get this id. I used this code in content-product.php

Please help to get this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$product_terms = wp_get_object_terms( 17, 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );
```

and then get the parent cat id and move all sub cat into an array.